# How To sort Dictionary After Adding data to it (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Hello Everyone my problem is when i add the data to Dictionary in c# and i want to switch (Sortype) string to check how the user wants the order data
like this:

```
                         string SortType="ByDownloads";
                         Dictionary<string, Data> WorldInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(Res.Body.ToString());
                            switch (SortType)
                            {
                                case "ByDownloads":
                                    WorldInfo.OrderByDescending(AllData => AllData.Value.PostDownloads).ToList();
                                    break;
                                case "ByViews":
                                    WorldInfo.OrderBy(AllData => AllData.Value.PostViews).ToList();
                                    break;
                            }
```

In this way, the code Will Not work and the Data does not sorted
but when i use this way the code will work:

```
Dictionary<string, Data> WorldInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(Res.Body.ToString());
var NewSortedDictionary = WorldInfo.OrderByDescending(AllData => AllData.Value.PostViews).ToList();
```

So I'm looking for the right way to do it and use (WorldInfo) Dictionary and switch (SortType) then i use it instead of (NewSortedDictionary).
Thank you :)

Comment: But.. you set Sortype to a value that doesn't then appear in the switch statement

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was wrong about some things, I updated the code to see where the problem is

Comment: Avoid confusing yourself - you cannot sort a Dictionary<T,U> - what you're doing is enumerating and sorting the content of the dictionary and storing into a list of key value pairs and calling it a dictionary; it isn't, so you shouldn't

Comment: Dictionaries are not sorted. Do you mean SortedList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks For Everyone Who Comment on this Question :) i fixed it using this way,i hope it help someone in the future:

```
            SortType="ByDownloads";
            Dictionary<string, Data> NormallDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(Res.Body.ToString());
            List<KeyValuePair<string,Data>> MySortedDictionary=  new List<KeyValuePair<string, Data>>();
            switch (SortType)
            {
                case "ByDownloads":
                MySortedDictionary = NormallDictionary.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Downloads).ToList();
                break;
                case "ByViews":
                MySortedDictionary = NormallDictionary.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.Views).ToList();
                break;
            }
```

*Now You Can Use MySortedDictionary as You Want*

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work in your case is because OrderByDescending returns an object after ordering.

You can do something like this

```
        Dictionary<string, Data> MyDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(Res.Body.ToString()));
        var data = Sortype == "ByViews" ? WorldInfo.OrderByDescending(AllData => AllData.Value.WorldPDownloads).ToList() : Sortype == 'ByDownloads' ? WorldInfo.OrderBy(AllData => AllData.Value.WorldPDownloads).ToList() : null;
```

Or

```
        string Sortype = "ByDate";
        Dictionary<string, Data> MyDictionary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Data>>(Res.Body.ToString());
        switch (Sortype)
        {
            case "ByViews":
                WorldInfo = WorldInfo.OrderByDescending(AllData => AllData.Value.WorldPDownloads).ToList();
                break;
            case "ByDownloads":
                WorldInfo =WorldInfo.OrderBy(AllData => AllData.Value.WorldPDownloads).ToList();
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :), I was wrong about some things, I updated the code to see where the problem is i just want to use (WorldInfo) Dictionary and switch sorttype then i use it instead of (NewSortedDictionary)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you are doing now and what do you expect?

Comment: @CaptainPrice If you think this answer was correct, mark it as well. future users might benefit from this

Comment: Thank you for your attention to this issue, I fixed it
I wish you a happy life :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that is a bug or just missing on purpose but you are setting `string Sortype ="ByDate";` without actually having a `"ByDate"` in the `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , (ByDate) its just a public string in Data Class but the problem when i try to sort Dictionary

Comment: As a temporary solution you could try extracting the data into a separate `List` before ordering: 

`var tempList =  WorldInfo.Select(AllData => AllData.Value.PostDownloads).ToList();
tempList.OrderByDescending(o => o);`

That being said, it is strange that you method does not work, what exactly is the input and what is the expected incorrect output?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I made some changes and it works now :) , happy coding